# static_pointer_cast resulting in a shared_ptr that points to a different location

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have made a `World` class to store a list of derived `Object`. I have ended up with the below:

```
class World {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> object_ptr;

public:
    template<class T> void registerObject(T& object) {
        auto sp = std::shared_ptr<T>(&object, [](T*){});
        object_ptr op = std::static_pointer_cast<Object>(sp);
        objects_.push_back(op);
    }

private:
    std::list<object_ptr> objects_;
};
```

I stumbled across something which is confusing me. The `static_pointer_cast` is resulting in a pointer that points 4 bytes after the original pointer (`sp`) for every other class that `T` implements. (I hope that made sense)

For instance:
I add this line to `registerObject`

```
std::cout << "sp:\t\t" << sp.get() << "\nop:\t\t" << op.get() << std::endl;
```

I then created the below classes:

```
class Object {
protected:
    int o; //the base classes can't be empty, the amount inside them doesn't effect anything as long as they're not empty.
};

class Bar {
protected:
    int b;
};

class Foo {
protected:
    int f;
};

class Derive1 : public Object {
};

class Derive2 : public Bar, public Object {
};

class Derive3 : public Foo, public Bar, public Object {
};
```

With this as my main function:

```
int main() {
    World w;
    Derive1 d1;
    Derive2 d2;
    Derive3 d3;

    std::cout << "d1:\t\t" << &d1 << std::endl;
    w.registerObject(d1);

    std::cout << "d2:\t\t" << &d2 << std::endl;
    w.registerObject(d2);

    std::cout << "d3:\t\t" << &d3 << std::endl;
    w.registerObject(d3);

    return 0;
}
```

And get this output:

```
Deriving 0 other classes:
d1: 0xbf91f41c
sp: 0xbf91f41c
op: 0xbf91f41c
Deriving 1 other class:
d2: 0xbf91f414
sp: 0xbf91f414
op: 0xbf91f418
Deriving 2 other classes:
d3: 0xbf91f408
sp: 0xbf91f408
op: 0xbf91f410
```

The only way I have managed to get `op` pointing to the same address as `sp` is if the other base classes are empty.

So why is this happening? It still points to the object, just not the same address.

Sorry if this is a silly question. I've tried to work it out myself and I have a "theory" but I've only just finished my first year of CS at Uni and this has me a bit out of my depth.

Comment: Welcome to the lovely world of multiple inheritance..

Answer (score 2):

It's not specific to `static_pointer_cast`, as a normal `static_cast` will exhibit the same behavior. This is typically how an implementation will handle multiple inheritance. The object pointer will point to a different location depending on which type it's really pointing to.

Comment: Why does it point to a different location though? I thought that it would point to the same location but just look at it differently.